# Successful login even with wrong credentials?

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, express

I'm pretty new to the JavaScript Framework and I am still very unsure of a lot of stuff about it.
So my problem pretty much is, when I click the submit button for my login form, it acts as if it successfully logged in. Although when checked in the network response, it would either say

> "Cannot read property 'password' of null"

if you typed a non-existent user but

> "Player does not exist."

when a wrong password is given.

**models/Players.js from backend**

```
players.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
console.log(req.body);
await Player.findOne({
   where: {
       username: req.body.username
   }
 })
   .then(player => {
       if(bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, player.password)) {
           let playertoken = jwt.sign(player.dataValues, process.env.SECRET_KEY, { expiresIn: 1440 });
           res.json({ playertoken: playertoken });
       } else {
           res.send("Player does not exist.");
       }
   })
   .catch(err => {
       res.send("Error: " + err);
   })});
```

***UserFunctions.js from frontend***

```
export const login = player => {
return axios
    .post('http://localhost:4000/players/login', {
        username: player.username,
        password: player.password
    })
    .then(response => {
        localStorage.setItem('playertoken', response.data);
        return response.data;
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        throw err;
    });};
```

***Homepage.js***

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { login } from '../../UserFunctions'
import './HomePage.css';

class HomePage extends Component {

constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        username: '',
        password: '',
        errors: {}
    };

    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
}

onChange(e) {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
}

onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const player = {
        username: this.state.username,
        password: this.state.password
    };

    login(player).then(res => {
        if (res) {
            this.props.history.push('/')
        }
    })
}

render() {

    const nLoggedInText = (
        <h4>Please Log in.</h4>
    );

    const loggedInText = (
        <div>
            <h4>In here you will be able to track your training progress, match stats and body comparisons.</h4>
            <h4>You may now begin tracking your progress have fun!</h4>
        </div>
    );

    const logInForm = (
        <div className="row d-flex justify-content-center">
            <div className="col-lg-3 rounded border">
                <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit} className="m-3">
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label htmlFor="username">Username</label>
                        <input
                            className="form-control"
                            name="username"
                            placeholder="username"
                            value={this.state.username}
                            onChange={this.onChange}
                            required
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                        <input
                            className="form-control"
                            type="password"
                            name="password"
                            placeholder="password"
                            value={this.state.password}
                            onChange={this.onChange}
                            required
                        />
                    </div>

                    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-bulldogs">Log In</button>

                </form>

            </div>
        </div>
    );


    return (
        <div className="container">
            <h1 className="nBrand">BULLDOGS</h1>
            <h3>Welcome {}!</h3>
            {localStorage.playertoken ? loggedInText : nLoggedInText}

            {!localStorage.playertoken ? logInForm : null}


        </div>
    );
}}
export default HomePage;
```

[homepage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqvum.png)

[login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zun7.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So my problem pretty much is, when I click the submit button for my login form, it acts as if it successfully logged in.
>   [Even though there was an error.]

I'm going to assume what's happening is your UserFunctions.js is running it's `.then`
even though your server sent an error. Axios will reject the request's promise when
you send an error code from the server outside of the 200-299 range. 200 is the default
status code when sending responses in express. We can change one of your status codes to the unauthorized
http status code (which is 401) with `res.status(401)`, this basically tells your frontend
something went wrong authenticating (it can also be used to say the user is not authenticated
to use a particular resource). Here's a list of other status codes and their meanings
that are useful: [Wikipedia's HTTP Status Code List](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes).

One other status that will be helpful for your code is the 500 status code which stands
for internal server error. You basically send this if something unexpected happened during
the request and the server was unable to handle the request.

These next two things are just suggestions, so feel free to take them with a grain of salt. You are getting 
"Cannot read property 'password' of null", because `player` in `player.password` is `null`. 
This means your call to find the user Player.findOne couldn't find a user with that 
username and so returned null. You just need to do add a check to see if player exists.

One last thing it's best not to send unexpected internal server errors and error objects in general
 to the client but instead log them in your server console and send back a generic response.
 This is mainly for security reasons.

So, let's change those things in your server code:

```js
players.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
console.log(req.body);
await Player.findOne({
   where: {
       username: req.body.username
   }
 })
   .then(player => {
       if(player && bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, player.password)) {
           let playertoken = jwt.sign(player.dataValues, process.env.SECRET_KEY, { expiresIn: 1440 });
           res.json({ playertoken: playertoken });
       } else {
           res.status(401).send("Wrong user password combination.");
       }
   })
   .catch(err => {
       console.error(err);
       res.status(500).send("Something unexpected happened.");
   })});
```

You also probably want to send the error to the user if it happens. This
can be done with your `errors` state you already had configured. Some of the
code below has been redacted just to better highlight to you what has changed.

```js
// ...redacted...

class HomePage extends Component {
// ...redacted...

onSubmit(e) {

    // ...redacted...

    login(player).then(res => {
        if (res) {
            this.props.history.push('/')
        }
    })
    .catch(err => {
        this.setState({
            errors: err,
        })
    })
}

render() {

    // ...redacted...


    return (
        <div className="container">
            <h1 className="nBrand">BULLDOGS</h1>
            <h3>Welcome {}!</h3>

            {this.state && this.state.errors && this.state.errors.message && <h4>Errors: {this.errors.message}}</h4>}

            {/* ...redacted */}

        </div>
    );
}}
export default HomePage;
```

Comment: Works like a charm! By the way I was planning on implementing some toast notifications with the authentication. Where would I implement it and how?

Comment: @jericoluislua It’s sort of up to you how you do it. If your notifications are coming from your backend you could either long-poll the backend, or set up web sockets. You could even look into the notifications api for the Frontend https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notifications_API/Using_the_Notifications_API.